# What is the difference between data-dismiss and hide(API) in Twitter BootStrap 3

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any difference between data-dismiss and hide(API) in Twitter BootStrap 3?

We use `data-dismiss="modal"` to close the modal.

We also call API `$("#modalId").modal("hide")` to close modals.

Both of them can trigger `hide.bs.modal` event . But what's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functionally they will both achieve the same outcome: closing the dialog.

The advantage of using the `data-dismiss` attribute is that you don't need *any* JavaScript code to let your user close the dialog; you can do everything in markup.  If you don't have any other JS code running on your page then the ability to get interaction without adding a JS dependency is pretty great.

The advantage of directly calling the API is that it gives you more flexibility: you can (as @amyogiji states) call it after you have done something else (like an AJAX call); you can prevent the user closing the dialog based on some validation rules; you can make something unrelated to the dialog close the dialog without the user needing to interact.

As with most decisions in software, there are use cases for both!  Generally I would recommend using the simplest solution (i.e. `data-dismiss`) until you need the extra flexibility.

Comment: Thanks for such detailed explanation ! So in function level, they do the exact same thing. But markup is simple and API provides more flexibility !  And I'm so sorry that I can't vote your answer for my reputation less than 15.

Comment: @Pencilcap happy to help.  FYI you may not be able to vote but you can accept this as the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

so there are two ways to dismiss or hide the modal .

**case 1 `data-dismiss="modal"`**

we use  `data-dismiss="modal"` if we want to close the modal without doing any activity or its the text modal , user have read it and now he wants to close it.

**case 2 `$(#"modalId").modal("hide")`**

we call $(#"modalId").modal("hide") using JavaScript this can be a scenario where modal ask the user to input some kind of data and if the data is successful modal should close . for e.g ajax call

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "posturl",
      data: data,
      success: function()
      {
        $(#"modalId").modal("hide")
      }
```

in the above example let's assume you have a modal with form which calls an ajax call. then on success you would like to close that form.

this is how i have used till now.

Answer (score 0):

When using multiple models on one page open at the same time on top of each other dismissing the topmost with data-dismiss="modal" will hide all active models.You can use all Bootstrap plugins purely through the markup API without writing a single line of JavaScript. This is Bootstrap's first class API and should be your first consideration when using a plugin.

Comment: Tanks for your answer. Does the value for `data-dismiss` markup means which modal to close ?